# Filter for customer reviews. Show or hide for default?

Tags: ux-field

I am working on customer reviews section for Mobile App. I have a question about review's filter. 
**Case A**. Show review’s filters on top of the page and push reviews down out of the first screen.
**Case B**. Hide review’s filters under "Filter" button and save vertical space.
[image]
What do you think guys?

Answer (score 2):

I think the **Second** approach is better.

With a clear keyword - *Filter*, it is far expected on what it will do.

Your first approach is limited to filter reviews through ratings, and hence is **not scalable**.

The second approach is far better since it is far less confusing and it also is expected that a User will be in the Reviews section of the page if he wants to read those reviews, thus making it easier to notice the filter option rather than it being on the top. Also, this is a good option for scalability if you plan to add more sorting methods into your app.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st option is better as long as its summary of the kind of rating and not the detailed individual reviews. Generally as a rule of thumb I try to avoid using modal boxes on mobile devices.

Comment: I don't see any reason to do not use modal window on mobile devices? Could you explain me why it's a rule of thumb for you?

Answer (score 1):

When reading reviews for a product or a service the users are most likely to read both the good and the bad reviews. So more than emphasising on a feature to filter reviews like on Case A, **showing the latest reviews** or **the most useful reviews** is more important.

So from your scenarios **Case B** is the most sensible approach because,

- The filter option is visible and the user can easily make the connection between the reviews and the button. The Case A approach, I didn't immediately think it was a filter. I thought it was only a graph representing ratings and it's asking me to rate the product.
- It's available for the user to click **IF** they want to use it. Users are most likely to look at the newest or the most useful reviews. If they want to filter the results the option is available. Case A is just screaming at the user's face.

Answer (score 0):

The **Second** approach is better.

Filters are not a primordial information then you can optimize your space with a "Filter" button.

Comment: As you can notice it's not just a filter but also very useful information about how many positive/negative/neutral reviews are there. I think version A is a better solution. Actually "big brothers" like Amazon, Walmart, target, bestbuy etc use version A case for reviews.